# How to detect when parts of a file have been overwritten?

Tags: file, io, filesystems

Long story short: I am attempting to stream a TV recording made with Windows Media Center. Normally I could just pipe the associated file, but Media Center allocates its recording files in 500MB blocks - so as soon as a recording is started, it allocates 500MB. When it gets close to using all that space, it allocates 1GB. And so on. Unfortunately piping this means that it consumes the first 500MB immediately, even though there is only a few megabytes of actual usable data in there.

What is the best/most performant way to track what is actually going on with the file? I'm imagining it would be possible to slice the 500MB file into five hundred 1MB segments, MD5 hash them, then regularly check which segments have changed. But is there a more sensible way to go about this?

Comment: How do you know the write pattern within each 500MB block?  How would your md5 check determine if your 1 MB segment was fully or just partially written?  Are you certain that no updates are ever made to each 500 MB block after writing has progressed to the next block?  Nevermind continually reading the file for the purpose of doing an md5 sum will likely significantly slow the writing of that file.

Comment: The proper way would be to track file write operations with a filesystem filter driver, and then stream only what has been written.